# How can I send a value to a modal and read it in modal's component? Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I Want to open quickViewModal and send an id and read it in the modal component.

Can anyone help me?
The next code is the html where I call the modal

```html
<div class="icon swipe-to-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quickViewModal">
            <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
          </div>
```

And the next one is the html of the modal. The modal is in diferent html file and in has his own .ts

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="quickViewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
```

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In these scenarios better would just keep your selected id somewhere in the variable and access into the view wherever you want to use

Answer (score 0):

If there is a parent child relation.

In parent.html,

```
<div>
    <div class="icon swipe-to-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quickViewModal" (click)="onModalOpen(divRef)"
        id="divId" #divRef>
        <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <modal-comp [id]="valueInParent"></modal-comp>
</div>
```

In parent.ts,

```
onModalOpen(divIdRef){
    this.valueInParent=divIdRef.id;
  }
```

In modal-comp.ts,

```
export class ModalComponent  {
  @Input() id: string;
}
```

In modal-comp.html,

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="quickViewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>{{id}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

You can also find working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5xieek)

Also if there is no parent-child relation between above Components then do it via `Injectable Service`.

I hope this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Than you so much for your response, but what if both has it own html and his own .ts file. @srp

Comment: Is there any parent-child relations btwn those two components or they are at same hierarchy?